# Best way to encrypt file on Ubuntu but readable on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, files, encryption

What would be the best way to encrypt a file in `Ubuntu 12.04` but in a way that could be read by a `Windows 8` user?

Would creating a Truecrypt volume work if I just sent the truecrypt file over?

Any other methods?

Comment: http://www.freeotfe.org/ Works for luks volumes.  And you can have files that mount with losetup on the linux side and freeotfe on the Windows side.

Comment: what is the point first to encrypt stuff, which later is readable in windows 8? any -seldomly- occuring windows malware hence can read all your data, right? sure you keep win8 clean ;) No offence intented, but I would really like to know what could be the reasoning behind this. I am quite glad that my Win cannot read my linux partitions

Comment: @hbdgaf FreeOTFE was discontinued in 2013, and a fork sprung up: [DoxBox](https://github.com/t-d-k/doxbox). It's still "Compatible with Linux encryption, Cryptoloop "losetup", dm-crypt, and LUKS. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are good to go with TrueCrypt.

In case you want to encrypt the whole system drive you must refer this guide
http://jan-krueger.net/development/truecrypt-system-drive-on-linux